# Disable Ansible's Powershell Encoding

Tags: windows, powershell, security, encoding, ansible

Ansible ships work to Windows endpoints by encoding the Powershell and shipping a blob to the remote machine(s). It is difficult to figure out what is happening from a security perspective when this work is executed. Semi-advanced security tooling sometimes **blocks** this activity between Ansible and the host it needs to remediate.

Does Ansible, when working against windows hosts, have a switch to disable this Powershell *masking* of what it's doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, **No** - there is no switch to disable Powershell `EncodedCommand`.

I asked this same question on [the related GitHub repository](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/50107#issuecomment-448442954) and received a detailed answer from one of the other Ansible contributors explaining why they wouldn't build one out.